# Is there a fork of node-multi-hashing that is able to compile with nodejs > 0.10?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-pool-setup

I'm messing with old node-cryptonote-pool code.

I would like to upgrade nodejs (currently sitting on 0.10.48) but when I'm changing the node version I cannot do npm update. Package node-multi-hashing is failing to compile. What I can see in logs is this:

```
error: ‘NewSymbol’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’
```

Is there any fork of this node-multi-hashing that will compile on nodejs > 0.10?